# CC to the email ID already in the forwarding list

Tags: email, smtp, forwarding

I've setup forwarding on an email say `alice@example.com` such that any incoming mail on this id is forwarded to `bob@example.com`.

This forwarding behavior is working fine.

I sent a mail from a gmail to `alice@example.com` keeping `bob@example.com` in CC and I got just a single mail on `bob@example.com` instead of two (one via forwarding from mailserver of `alice@example.com` and one from the sender's mailserver i.e. gmail who kept the mail ID in cc).

The only mail I got is via the mailserver of `alice@example.com` (I verified this from mail headers).

Why is it so ?

Comment: Your mail address examples were quite hard to read. If you actually own that domain just revert the edit. Did you check your mailserver log for information on what happened and/or did you thoroughly check your client that the mail didn't end up in the spam folder or was recorded as part of a conversation?

Comment: @Seth: Thanks I've reverted back to your edit with slight modifications. Yes I've thoroughly checked, the client got just one mail. I've mentioned in my original question what the mail header says.

Comment: "It's a feature, not a bug". How are you forwarding from alice to bob? Some forwarders are smart enough to realize you'll end up getting two copies and just send you one copy. The sendmail `metoo` setting may have something to do with it as well, though that "solves" a slightly different issue.